# Functioning Heroku-deployed Twitter bot stills shows Application error?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, twitter, bots

I have a functioning Twitter bot ([@Sunlight_Bot](https://twitter.com/Sunlight_Bot)) deployed on Heroku that stills shows this error:

[image: Heroku error]

The logs show a error H14, which I believe is occuring simply because the dyno is shut down while my bot is waiting (`setInterval`) between posts, correct?

```
2019-04-23T22:26:16.989176+00:00 app[api]: Release v81 created by user <user>
2019-04-23T22:26:16.989176+00:00 app[api]: Deploy ... by user <user>
2019-04-23T22:26:17.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2019-04-23T22:26:18.042459+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2019-04-23T22:26:18.104139+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 143
2019-04-23T22:26:19.664782+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `node app.js`
2019-04-23T22:26:20.333252+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2019-04-23T22:27:53.987454+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=<host> request_id=<id> fwd="<fwd>" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-04-23T22:27:54.206902+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=<host> request_id=<id> fwd="<fwd>" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

**Why is Heroku still showing this Application Error despite the bot apperently functioning? Is this something that I can/should fix?**

Here's the code. `setInterval` calls the `tweeter()` function once every six hours. The function gets some data from a Heroku PostgreSQL database, formats it, and posts it to Twitter as one or more Tweets.

```
function tweeter() {

    stafferInfo = {};
    tweetString = '';

    let pool = new pg.Pool({
        connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
        ssl: true
    } || config.db);

    pool.connect()

        .then(client => {
            pgClient = client;
            return pgClient.query(randomRow)
                .then(res => {
                    stafferInfo = res.rows[0];   // (1) GET INFO FROM DB AND SET VARIABLE
                    // console.log(stafferInfo);

                })
                .catch(err => console.error('Error executing first psql query', err.stack));
        })

        .then(() => {
            return pgClient.query(updateTweeted) // (2) UPDATE "TWEETED" COUNT
                .then(res => {
                    // console.log(res);
                })
                .catch(err => console.error('Error executing second psql query', err.stack));
        })
        .then(() => {                     // (3) POST TWEET
            tweetString = formatTweet(stafferInfo);

            if ((`${tweetString} (data from ProPublica's Trump Town dataset)`).length <= (280)) {
                tweetString += ` (data from ProPublica's Trump Town dataset)`
            }
            else if (tweetString.length <= 280) {

                console.log(tweetString);

                sendTweet(tweetString);

                if (stafferInfo.linkedin_url) {
                    console.log(formatLinkedIn(stafferInfo));
                    sendTweet(formatLinkedIn(stafferInfo));
                }
                if (stafferInfo.resume_document_url) {
                    console.log(formatResume(stafferInfo));
                    sendTweet(formatResume(stafferInfo));
                }
                if (stafferInfo.financial_disclosure_url) {
                    console.log(formatFinancialDisclosure(stafferInfo));
                    sendTweet(formatFinancialDisclosure(stafferInfo));
                }
                if (stafferInfo.ethics_waiver_url) {
                    console.log(formatEthicsWaiver(stafferInfo));
                    sendTweet(formatEthicsWaiver(stafferInfo));
                }
            }
            else {
                console.log(`Tweet is longer than 280 characters: ${tweetString}`);
            }
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error('Error acquiring client: ', err.stack);  // IF ERROR THROW TO CONSOLE
        })
        .finally(() => {                                // EITHER WAY SHUT DOWN CLIENT & POOL AFTER
            if (pgClient) {
                pgClient.release();
            }
            pool.end(); // pool shutdown
        });
}

// tweeter(); // For testing

setInterval(tweeter, 6*60*60*1000);
```

Comment: Did the below answer your question?

Comment: I understand why `method=GET path="/"` will throw an error, since there's no HTTP server, but aren't Heroku's errors (both in the browser and in the terminal) pretty arcane and unhelpful in cases like this? Is there any way to know that a twitter bot is actually running on Heroku besides `Build succeeded` followed by a bunch of weird errors? :) Thanks for your help by the way. I'm happy to mark as answered, but just hoping to learn more for my own knowledge in the future...

Comment: The error in the log does say "No web processes running" :-)  I've edited my answer to give you an example of how you can add an HTTP server and have it give a basic status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your bot does not start an HTTP server so you shouldn’t expect it to respond to a request.

If you'd like to have your bot respond to HTTP requests, you can install express, and have it respond with some kind of status. First install `express`

```
npm install express
```

And then add to your bot:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
let tweet_count = 0;

// Insert your bot here
// And modify it to increment `tweet_count` when it sends a msg

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send(`Twitter bot is up and running! Tweets sent: ${tweet_count}`));

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Twitter bot http server listening on port ${port}!`));
```